# VBA: get the column number of a selection

Tags: vba

I want to get the column number of a selection after using the Application InputBox but it always has bugs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim cln1 as Integer

selection1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the fist column.", Title:="First Column")

cln1 = selection1.Cells(1, 1).Column

debug.print(cln1)
```

I am not sure why this does't work..Can someone tell me how to correct this?Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? I don't quite follow. Also, is it throwing an error? Where is it htrowing the error?

Comment: What do you want c1n1 to be?

Comment: And the error is from this line: cln1 = selection1.Cells(1, 1).Column

Comment: Maybe give an example in your question, i.e. If the user wishes to select column E, what should selection1 and c1n1 equal? Sorry I am confuse by your coding a bit, but I think I can help you out if I get this info

Comment: Yes for sure! if the user selects Column E, then selection1 should be all the numbers in column E, and cln1 should be 5. Another example will be, the user selects the data in B3:B17, then cln1 should be "2" because the column number of the selection is Column B, and the selection1 should be all the data in B3:B17. When I ran the code and it says "run-time error 424, Object required".

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, please accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, put this in your sub:

```
Dim selection1 As Range
Dim cln1 As Integer

Set selection1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the fist column.", Title:="First Column", Type:=8)

cln1 = selection1.Cells(1, 1).Column

MsgBox cln1
```

Type:= 8 Lets it know that selection1 is a Range Object